how to handle the ungraceful disconnection in grpc python server when using streaming response?
I'm develop a bidirectional streaming rpc and test it with a simple client. I found the server doesn't work as expected when the client is killed. For convenience, I will give a simple example:
import demo_pb2, demo_pb2_grpc
import grpc
import time
from concurrent import futures
import traceback

class DemoService(demo_pb2_grpc.DemoServiceServicer):
    def DemoRPC(self, request_iterator, context):
        try:
            for req in request_iterator:
                time.sleep(1)
                print("receive request")
                yield demo_pb2.DemoResponse(resp=req.arg + "_resp")
        except grpc.RpcError as e:
            print("grpc connection disconnect")
        except Exception as e:
            print("error: {}, trace: {}".format(e, traceback.format_exc()))
        print("finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread_pool = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
    service = DemoService()
    server = grpc.server(thread_pool)
    demo_pb2_grpc.add_DemoServiceServicer_to_server(
        service, server
    )
    server.add_insecure_port("[::]:50001")
    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()

when the client exits normally, I get following output(the client sends 10 requests):
receive request
receive request
receive request
receive request
receive request
receive request
receive request
receive request
receive request
receive request
finished

but when I kill the client while it's running, I got following output:
receive request
receive request
receive request
receive request

as shown above, either finished nor the exception message is printed. I debug the server and find it caused by the yield statement after disconnection, so it can be solved by check whether connection is still alive by context.is_active(). A modified example as follow:
import demo_pb2, demo_pb2_grpc
import grpc
import time
from concurrent import futures
import traceback

class DemoService(demo_pb2_grpc.DemoServiceServicer):
    def DemoRPC(self, request_iterator, context):
        try:
            for req in request_iterator:
                time.sleep(1)
                print("receive request")
                if context.is_active():
                    yield demo_pb2.DemoResponse(resp=req.arg + "_resp")
        except grpc.RpcError as e:
            print("grpc connection disconnect")
        except Exception as e:
            print("error: {}, trace: {}".format(e, traceback.format_exc()))
        print("finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread_pool = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
    service = DemoService()
    server = grpc.server(thread_pool)
    demo_pb2_grpc.add_DemoServiceServicer_to_server(
        service, server
    )
    server.add_insecure_port("[::]:50001")
    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()

However, there is still risk because following code:
if context.is_active():
    yield demo_pb2.DemoResponse(resp=req.arg + "_resp")

is not an atomic operation. The client may be killed after the if statement so this error still occurs.
I find similar problem in this stackoverflow quesiont and seems to be fixed according to this github issue. But I still meet this problem. I'm using python 3.10 with grpcio==1.62.0 on ubuntu 20.04.
